# how to init tinymce with onlick button jquery

Tags: jquery, tinymce

This is by function

```
function tinyMCEINIT() {
  tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea.text_editor",
    theme: "modern",
    height: 150,
    plugins: [
      "advlist autolink link image lists charmap hr anchor pagebreak",
      "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
      "table directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager code tiny_mce_wiris"
    ],
    toolbar1: "bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | forecolor backcolor code tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditor tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditorChemistry tiny_mce_wiris_CAS",
    // toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
    image_advtab: true,
    external_filemanager_path: "<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>js/tinymce/plugins/filemanager/",
    filemanager_title: "Raiseforme Filemanager",
    external_plugins: {
      "filemanager": "<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>js/tinymce/plugins/filemanager/plugin.min.js",
      // "tiny_mce_wiris": "<?php //echo $this->webroot;   ?>js/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/plugin.js",
    }
  });
}
```

and I am using it on append `html` like below

```
$(".add-new-ans").append(html);

tinyMCEINIT();
```

Comment: So what is the issue that you are facing.

Comment: are you talking about `document.getElementById('yourbuttonid').addEventListener("click", tinyMCEINIT)` or `$('#yourbuttonid').on("click", function(){tinyMCEINIT();});`?

Comment: texteditor showing in disabled mode

Comment: this might help http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/655046/Enable-Disable-Readonly-TinyMCE-Editor-using-JavaScript-or-Server-Side/